# Matlab matrix dimagree error only in standalone app

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-compiler

I have to convert my Matlab function to a standalone application. I build it using the Matlab build tool, that part is ok. 
However, I get a dimagree error while running my standalone program, even if it works just fine in Matlab; here the code which seems to be wrong :

```
% INITIALISATIONS
% find connected components
cc = bwconncomp(bw);
% find areas and centroids
stats = regionprops(cc, 'Area','Centroid');
% keep only the particles in the right dimensions
all_areas = cat(1, stats(:).Area);
idx = zeros(size(all_areas));
fprintf('\nSize all_areas : %d %d \n',size(all_areas,1), size(all_areas,2));
fprintf('\nSize idx : %d %d \n',size(idx,1), size(idx,2));
fprintf('\nProgram paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause;
idx = all_areas > minArea & all_areas < maxArea;
```

Error shows up at the last line of the above code. I get :

```
??? Error using lt
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in ==> stats at 46
Error in ==> statPart at 83
MATLAB:dimagree
```

As you can see, I tried to initialize idx with zeros(), and I output the size of idx and all_areas, they are the same when I run the program. So I'm out of idea now, I really need help here...

[EDIT]

Here is the code I use to handle statPart function inputs :

```
function [BW2,stat] = statPart(varargin)
i = 1; 
while i<=length(varargin), 
    argok = 1; 
    if ischar(varargin{i}), 
        switch varargin{i}, 
            % argument IDs
            case 'minArea', i = i+1; minArea = varargin{i};
            case 'maxArea', i = i+1; maxArea = varargin{i}; 
            case 'subImgSize', i = i+1; subImgSize = varargin{i};
            case 'image', i = i+1; Igray = varargin{i};
            otherwise argok = 0; 
        end
    else
        argok = 0; 
    end
    if ~argok, 
        disp(['(statPart) Argument invalide ignore #' num2str(i+1)]); 
    end
    i = i+1; 
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is not in `idx`, since you're assigning a new value into it. I think `minArea` and `maxArea` are the problem. What size are they? Print their sizes too.

Comment: minArea and maxArea are supposed to be scalar values. I will check their values too and let you know, shouldn't be long thx

Comment: Looks like they're actually not scalars. Oh wow what's going on here...

Comment: Post the part where you compute `minArea` and `maxArea`...

Comment: Not quite, as you can see there are two functions, I pass minArea and maxArea as parameters to statPart in the command line as "minArea" 2 "maxArea" 20000 so how is this possible that they become 3x1 vectors with minArea=[50 48 48] and maxArea=[50 48 48] in stats...?

Comment: Are you checking `minArea` and `maxArea` at the beginning of `statPart`?

Comment: That'a what I'm coding right now, build just finished...

Comment: just before I call stats, in statPart, minArea==[50 48 48] and maxArea==[50 48 48], so I guess somehow Windows translates my input into something else??!

Comment: btw here is my function signature : function [BW2,stat] = statPart(varargin), I call it this way in DOS : disPart "minArea" 2 "maxArea" 20000

Comment: Yeah I just realized that, reading this http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/12/21/strings-and-numbers-as-arguments/ I think the Matlab isdeployed function then str2int is what I'm looking for. I wonder too about the 3 values :-S

Comment: Actually you need [`str2num`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html), which is the right function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states that he problem arises in `lt` (the less-than comparison) of this line:

```
idx = all_areas > minArea & all_areas < maxArea;
```

because  `minArea` and `maxArea` are not of the same dimensions `all_areas`. They either have to be of `size(all_areas)` or scalars, which they are not.

From your check, `minArea` and `maxArea` are `[50 48 48]`, which is the ASCII equivalent of "200". They are received as strings from the command line, and you should use [`str2num`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) to convert them into numbers before you handle their values.
I don't understand, however, why they are not equal to your input strings "2" and "20000". How are you parsing your input parameters? That would be a good place to start looking for the problem, but without additional information I won't be able to help you further.

Also, you mention in the comments that `disPart` calls `statPart`. What is `disPart`, and what is its relation to `statPart`?

Comment: disPart is the name of the standalone application, this is just the compiled version of statPart. I know it's confusing and I will change that in the future (I didn't want to have several files with the same name into the same folder)

Comment: Okay, so how do you handle the input command-line arguments? Please post the code, preferably embedded into the original question.

Comment: So, did you try using `str2num` inside the switch loop to obtain the numerical value of the input arguments? Also, I suggest putting `disp(cellfun(@ischar, C))` (or something similar) in the beginning of the code to see if all parameters are received as strings.

Comment: Hi, the values of minArea and maxArea are OK now, " if isdeployed str2num() " was the solution. Thanks EitanT !